# How am I suppose to access product purchase variables?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, transactional-mail, variables

I need to send an mail to customer on purchase.I am customizing the Invoice template.I need to show the product that he/she purchased when the email is sent.
Whenever a customer purchases a product from my store, system send sends an invoice mail to customer.However I need to customize the the default email template such that it also displays the product image in Invoice.In order to access the product id or image of a product from specific purchase I probably need a variable(as magento has variables which can be accessed in HTML) of a product.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is now way to modify items grid and add a variable like {{var_productImage}} from admin, you will have to duplicate *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml* to your template and add a new column

```
<td align="left" valign="top">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50, 50) ?> />
</td>
```

Comment: not exactly what was I looking for, but it was a help.Thank you.

Comment: if you want to add them to pdf invoice, maybe this could help you  http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-pdf-invoice-with-product-images-extension/